# Newer alternative or newer version of Fancyupload?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, mootools

I'm in need of a mootools upload widget. It seems that [Fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) is still at the top of most recommendations and searches for this category. However, the project appears to have been left untouched for at least a few years, and it seems to be non-functional in IE9, and is optimized for mootools 1.2.

I've also tried swfupload, but it's less polished and seems less active than fancyupload.

Are there newer tools that provide similar functionality? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Plupload from the tinyMCE guys:

http://www.plupload.com/

I didn't use it, but it looks great so far.